# How can I debug a launch configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, godot, vscode-tasks

We have a new team member trying to get started with our Godot project. VSCode is our standard editor. Everyone is using Fedora Linux. You can find the relevant files here:

https://github.com/redhat-gamedev/srt-godot-server/tree/main/.vscode

On my machine, when trying to run the launch configuration, the build task succeeds, and then the program is launched. Everything works fine.

On the new team member's machine, when trying to run the launch configuration, the build task succeeds, and then nothing happens. There are no errors. There is no output.

We tried running VSCode with an increased log level (`debug`), but the VScode log files don't show anything meaningful or related. We tried executing the equivalent launch command from the terminal/shell and it works fine. There are no errors, but the resulting built program executes successfully. Interestingly, running `code --verbose` does produce a ton of output but nothing super specific to the execution of the steps in the launch configuration. Also, `code --verbose --log debug` does not cause messages spit out of VSCode to be at the `DEBUG` log level. Everything is still `INFO`:

```
[4183395:0112/092541.932947:INFO:CONSOLE(616)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (parcel)] [CHANGED] ...
```

How can I debug a launch configuration in VSCode to see what's going on? Is there a way to make the launch configuration system of VSCode be more verbose?